# Best practice for counting values that contain NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am wondering if the best way to count a list of values that contains NULL values is by doing the following?

```
COUNT(ISNLL(Date),'')
```

I ask because I have a while loop that only runs if the count > 0. IT looks like this is working but but is it the proper way? Here is my code:

```
WHILE SELECT(Count(*)
             FROM 
              (SELECT 1 AS a
                   FROM dbo.tblrecords r
                   LEFT JOIN dbo.tblError e
                GROUP BY r.RecordId, r.MissingCount
                HAVING r.MissingCount > COUNT(DISTINCT(ISNULL(e.[ErrorDate],''))) > 0
```

If the e.ErrorDate is NULL I do not want it to count this.

Comment: What are you doing inside the `WHILE` loop? Perhaps there is a much more efficient, set-based way to do this than using a loop at all.

Comment: I think something else is happening in that while loop (I hope). It appears the question is: Is this the best way to count values that contain nulls (since nulls are eliminated by aggregate functions.)

Comment: I understand that the question was not "how can I make this while loop more efficient" - but I can't help but comment on it, since there is probably a way to achieve what you are doing inside the while loop without using a while loop. Imagine moving a stack of bricks... you can put them all in a wheelbarrow and move them in one shot, or you can move them one at a time. If the question was just about the query, why bother with the information about the `WHILE` loop at all? Seems irrelevant.

Comment: I just wanted to show that it was in a while loop because if the nulls are counted I could get caught in an infinite loop. The while loop is used along with a webservice call so the web service does not get over loaded. I could probably do this part with a temp table but the rest of it is beyond my power of changing how the webservice takes in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, ETC) will eliminate nulls so if you want them to be counted, you can either `COUNT(*)` which will count records, not individual values, or do as you're doing `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` to replace null values.

If you want to count *only* null values, do a count(*) where the value `IS NOT NULL` as @Derek Kromm suggested.

FWIW, I don't think the `DISTINCT` is necessary as it may throw off your count if you have multiple nulls that you wish to count as more than one.

Answer (score 2):

just add `WHERE e.ErrorDate is not null` to your query

Answer (score 0):

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable WHERE somefield IS NULL) > 0